# regex scan only returning first value

Tags: ruby, regex

I have two strings that should both return matches according to the regex, but only str1 returns the expected match. str1 is an exact match for the regex (created by Avinash Raj) below. str2 contains str1 and more data. I expected str2 to return str1 and more values that matched, but it returns nothing   Can someone explain why?

```
str1="3,15,14,31,40,5,5,4,5,3,4,4,5,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,3,3,3,2,4,3,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,3,3,3,2,3"
    str2="3,15,14,31,40,5,5,4,5,3,4,4,5,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,3,3,3,2,4,3,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,3,3,3,2,3,3,15,14,35,27,4,5,3,5,3,2,4,4,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,3,3,3,2,5,9,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,false,false,false,false,2,2,3,2,3,3,15,16,34,53,4,4,4,3,1,3,4,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,2,3,5,1,true,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,15,18,37,29,4,4,4,3,2,3,3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,2,4,1,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,15,20,34,37,4,4,4,3,1,3,3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,4,1,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,3,1,3,1,3,3,16,10,18,30,4,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,4,4,3,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,16,12,39,5,5,5,4,5,3,5,5,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,5,10,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,16,14,18,27,4,4,4,4,2,3,3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,true,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,16,16,18,32,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,5,3,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,true,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,16,18,20,7,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,16,20,18,59,4,4,4,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,4,5,9,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,17,10,16,9,3,3,3,3,1,2,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,5,1,true,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,17,12,16,17,4,3,4,2,1,4,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,5,3,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,17,14,16,21,4,4,4,4,1,3,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,17,16,16,20,5,5,4,5,3,4,4,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,8,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,17,18,16,31,4,4,4,4,1,4,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,5,1,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,true,false,true,false,false,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,17,20,18,8,5,5,4,5,4,4,4,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,5,1,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,18,10,31,33,3,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,7,true,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,18,12,36,11,4,4,4,5,3,4,3,3,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,5,1,false,false,false,true,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,18,14,49,6,3,3,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,9,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,18,16,32,53,3,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,3,5,7,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,18,18,37,59,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,5,7,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,19,10,5,25,4,4,4,2,2,4,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,5,1,true,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,2,1,3,2,3,3,19,13,0,5,5,5,4,5,3,3,5,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,5,7,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,19,14,5,23,4,4,4,4,3,4,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,5,9,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,19,16,7,19,5,4,4,4,3,4,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,5,9,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,19,18,6,30,4,4,4,4,3,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,8,false,false,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,true,false,false,false,true,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,19,20,8,25,4,4,5,4,3,4,3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,5,1,false,false,true,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,3,19,21,18,2,4,4,4,3,3,4,3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,1,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,true,false,true,false,false,false,true,false,false,3,2,3,2,3,"

    str1.scan(/^,?(?:[1-5]\d|[1-9])(?:,(?:[1-5]\d|[1-9])){4}(?:,[1-5]){21}(?:,(?:true|false)){27}(?:,[1-5]){5}$/).each{|x|
    puts x
    puts "---1---"
    }
    str2.scan(/^,?(?:[1-5]\d|[1-9])(?:,(?:[1-5]\d|[1-9])){4}(?:,[1-5]){21}(?:,(?:true|false)){27}(?:,[1-5]){5}$/).each{|x|
    puts x
    puts "---2---"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of by definition, you can't have more than one pattern match in a string when your pattern specifically says "start of string, then [stuff], then end of string". Look at regexp anchors `^` and `$`.

A simpler example might make it clearer: `^a$` "start of string, then letter `a`, then end of string" will match in `"a"` once, but will match in `"aaa"` zero times, even though there are three letters a.

Answer (score 1):

> $ assert position at end of a line

Now you are not matching upto the `end of line`.

```
^,?(?:[1-5]\d|[1-9])(?:,(?:[1-5]\d|[1-9])){4}(?:,[1-5]){21}(?:,(?:true|false)){27}(?:,[1-5]){5}
```

Just remove the `$` from the end.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/22

Answer (score 0):

Because you're regular starts with the `^` metacharacter and ends with the `$` metacharacter, it expects the full string to match.